# Includegraphics clipped parts still here even if not visible

Tags: graphics, pdf, includegraphics, clip

I am trying to use `\includegraphics` to remove unwanted parts of a pdf image. The current syntax I use is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = center] (passport) at (current page.center) {
    \includegraphics[page = 1, trim = 239.25mm 45mm 50.75mm 70mm, clip, angle = 2]{input.pdf}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I open the output file with `evince` or `okular`, it shows what I want.

However if I import the produced `pdf` in some image editing software, with some importation option, I can see that the parts of the input outside of the viewport are still there. How to remove all the "binary" data the `input.pdf` contains outside of the viewport? I was thinking that `clip` would do the job, but it does not as I manage to recover the data.

Comment: you would have to use some external application. Clipping images which contains curves etc is not a trivial task.

Comment: And what if we consider the case of just a scanned images?

Comment: pdftex never removes content clipping just means specifyig a rectangle and applying the PDF clip operator